# Extra newline output when using print() in Python

Tags: python, newline

I am brand new to Python. I am reading text from a file & replacing a word. I simply want to output the same two lines, with the word replacement, where the first line ends with a newline.

```
ADAMS, Ernie, 166 Winterstreamrose Way
NEWLINE, None, 1 Nomorenewlines Street
```

My test code is:

```
# readFileLines.py  --- testing file line reading, replacing text & dealing with newlines

with open("line.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word == 'Way':
                line = line.replace("Way", "Street")
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
ADAMS, Ernie, 166 Winterstreamrose Street

NEWLINE, None, 1 Nomorenewlines Street
```

Why do I get an extra newline between the output lines? I note, that like in `line.txt`, there is no newline after the second line of output.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading file with this idiom:

```
with open("line.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
```

The `line` comes with a `\n` character at the end.

Try this:

```
with open("line.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # Removes the "\n" character
        for word in line.split():
            if word == 'Way':
                line = line.replace("Way", "Street")
        print(line, end="\n") # Puts back the "\n" character.
```

Or you can use `print(line, end="")`. By default, `print()` ends with a `\n` char, you can specify the the `end=""` to be to avoid the extra newline with the line isn't striped when reading, i.e.

```
with open("line.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word == 'Way':
                line = line.replace("Way", "Street")
        print(line, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function adds the extra newline. It is actaully a basic formatter. If you want to emit to stdout the same as you read in you can use `sys.stdout.write()`.

this is more efficient.

```py
with open("line.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       if "Way" in line:
            line = line.replace("Way", "Street")
       sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: print already gave a new line after printng the line `ADAMS, Ernie, 166 Winterstreamrose Street` Right? why again a blank new line

Comment: check @alvas's answer, that is what is happening here

Comment: Exactly. So writing it back out without the extra formatting of `print` won't add extra newlines. Use the newline that's already in the text. There is also no need to split the line.

Comment: I think its a bad practice to rely on the fromatting present in the text file. cuz there could be cases where he may have just a single new line, in that case print's extra fromatting would be needed

Comment: If the goal is to keep the file exactly the same, except for replacing "Way" with "Street" then you really don't want to try and replace the line endings. That would be an unspecified change.

Comment: Actually @alvas's first answer was the simplest solution. Just strip the newline from `line\n` But these explanations still don't address why the newline is doubled for the first line but not added to the second. However I will mark @alvas's answer as the correct one.

Comment: That implementation will be slower. It has more steps than is required to perform the task that you specify.

Comment: Thanks Keith. Yes. I implemented your method. In the end it is the simplest. I note the indentation is important in Python. I take it that the call to `sys.stdout` references underlying C code. I assume therefore this will make it quicker.

Comment: I note the indentation is important in Python. My version has the call `sys.stdout.write(line)` at the same TAB column as the nested for loop (I see you have it one TAB over - this didn't give me the correct output) But when I corrected this all was good.

Comment: @Dave oops, yes, I had one extra space. Fixed it. BTW, both `print` and `sys.stdout` use the same C code. The difference is `print`, by default, appends a newline to the output. The `sys.stdout` writes whatever you give it, as-is. This code is not faster because of that, but because it doesn't do the extra steps of splitting the line. It does a substring search. In Python, strings are "immutable", and can't be altered in-place. Any string operations, such as split, result in new object allocations and data copies. Which are then immediately discarded, resulting in yet another call to free.